# Select case when null Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to use a case statement to return a value when either the data is null or the value is 99. Is this possible with oracle? Below is my code which does not work because is null and null throw an error. How can I have the sql statement return Y when the value is either NULL or 99 and N when the value is anything else?

```
SELECT CASE StudentStatus 
         WHEN '99' THEN 'Y' 
         WHEN IS NULL THEN 'Y' 
         ELSE 'N' 
     END From USERS
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT CASE 
         WHEN StudentStatus  = '99' THEN 'Y' 
         WHEN StudentStatus IS NULL THEN 'Y' 
         ELSE 'N' 
       END 
From USERS
```

OR

```
SELECT CASE 
         WHEN StudentStatus  = '99' OR StudentStatus IS NULL 
         THEN 'Y'              
         ELSE 'N' 
       END 
From USERS
```

Answer (score 3):

Do it the other way, let your `case` *expression* check when StudentStatus <> '99':

```
SELECT CASE when StudentStatus <> '99' then 'N'
         ELSE 'Y' 
       END
From USERS
```

Answer (score 1):

You could rewrite it using `DECODE`:

```
SELECT DECODE(StudentStatus, '99', 'Y', '', 'Y', 'N')
FROM Users
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=b46851ce06df2848eb8a1b91e897dbb3)**

Output:

```
+----------------+-------------------------------------------+
| STUDENTSTATUS  | DECODE(STUDENTSTATUS,'99','Y','','Y','N') |
+----------------+-------------------------------------------+
|            99  | Y                                         |
|                | Y                                         |
|           100  | N                                         |
+----------------+-------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `nvl()` function within `decode()` as :

```
 select decode(
               nvl(StudentStatus,99),
                                     99,'Y','N') as status
   from users
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=f41d6a70f9d055af37709951fb689eec)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

try using

```
SELECT CASE WHEN ( StudentStatus  = '99' OR StudentStatus IS NULL ) THEN 'Y' 
       ELSE 'N' END 
From USERS
```